# Hibernate without entities

Tags: hibernate

because of some reasons we have to call stored procedure from hibernate without creating entities, is it even possible to attain this?
If yes some bread crumbs are required to achieve this.

So in short ---

Problem statement
If we are not using entities to map database table via hbm file or via annotations, is it even possible to achieve this.

We are using hibernate template and are assigning session factory to it for creation of sessions viz.

```
@Autowired
public void init(SessionFactory ecommSessionFactory) {
    setSessionFactory(ecommSessionFactory);

}
```

here ecommSessionFactory has been defined in application-context.xml of spring

Comment: So, What is the problem ?

Comment: Problem is if we are not creating entities to map object to table via annotation or via hbm file, is there's any way to call stored procedure?

Comment: Just for information we are using hibernate template and assigning session factory to it.

Comment: Can you update this in your question. It shall be helpful to solve your problem

Comment: Done, do let me know if you have some way to achieve this

Comment: Why would you use Hibernate to call stored procedures only? Just use JDBC. Or Spring's Jdbc support.

Comment: "is it even possible to achieve this", achieve what?

Comment: Stefan if you read carefully you will know that I am talking about calling stored function via hibernate template without creating the entities

Comment: If you do not have entities, you can call the stored procedure just like any native SQL you can call. But why do you have Hibernate? What do you want to achieve with Hibernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your own SQL to insert, update, delete and even select data from the database. But there are clear expectations to the arguments.

```
<class name="Person">
    <id name="id">
        <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <property name="name" not-null="true"/>
    <sql-insert>exec createPerson ?, ?</sql-insert>
    <sql-delete>exec deletePerson ?</sql-delete>
    <sql-update>exec updatePerson ?, ?</sql-update>
</class>
```

See the [reference documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch18.html#querysql-cud).

I don't understand what you mean by "without entities". You still have entities, otherwise you don't need an ORM.